# migrating from Three.JS 51 to 54 (texture problems)

Tags: three.js, textures, migrating

i'm having some problems migrating my code to the newest release of Three.JS.
I've already tried alot, but my models keep looking black (the color function seems broken)) and as soon as I try loading a model with a texture, it crashes.
I know some things have changed regarding textures in the transition from r52 to r53 but I can't seem to implement it right. I use a dynamic loading system to cache JSON models.

Currently the code looks like this:

```
 var MB = MB || {};
    MB.Part = function () {
        this.id = MB.ObjectCount++;
        this.type = 'part';
        this.name = '';
        this.reference = undefined;
        this.mesh = undefined;
        this.colour = undefined;
        this.texture = undefined;
        this.Object3D = undefined;
        this.parent = undefined;
        this.visible = true;
        this.position = new THREE.Vector3();
        this.rotation = new THREE.Vector3();
        MB.Objects[this.id] = this
    };
    MB.Part.prototype.load = function (reference, name, mesh, color, texture, position, rotation, visible, visible3D, callback) {
        var context = this;
        if (!position) position = new THREE.Vector3();
        if (!rotation) rotation = new THREE.Vector3();
        if (this.isGeometrySetup(mesh, texture)) {
            this.insert(context, reference, name, mesh, color, texture, position, rotation, visible, visible3D);
            if (callback) callback()
        } else {
            var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader(false);
            loader.load(PATH + 'data/parts/json/' + mesh + '.js', function (geometry) {
                context.setupGeometry(geometry, mesh, texture);
                context.insert(context, reference, name, mesh, color, texture, position, rotation, visible, visible3D);
                if (callback) callback()
            })
        }
    };
    MB.Part.prototype.insert = function (context, reference, name, mesh, color, texture, position, rotation, visible, visible3D) {
        context.reference = reference;
        context.mesh = mesh;
        context.name = name;
        if (color) context.colour = color;
        if (texture) context.texture = texture;
        context.visible = visible;
        if (color) {
            context.setupColour(color);
            var Object3D = new THREE.Mesh(MB.Library.geometries[mesh], MB.Library.colours[color])
        } else if (texture) {
            var Object3D = new THREE.Mesh(MB.Library.geometries[texture], new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial())
        }
        context.Object3D = Object3D;
        context.Object3D.doubleSided = true;
        context.position.copy(position);
        context.rotation.copy(rotation);
        Object3D.Object = context;
        Object3D.scale.set(SCALE, SCALE, SCALE);
        Object3D.position.copy(context.position);
        Object3D.rotation.copy(context.rotation);
        Object3D.visible = visible3D;
        MB.Object3Ds[Object3D.id] = Object3D
    };
    MB.Part.prototype.isGeometrySetup = function (mesh, texture) {
        if (texture) {
            if (!MB.Library.geometries[texture]) return false;
            else return true
        } else {
            if (!MB.Library.geometries[mesh]) return false;
            else return true
        }
    };
    MB.Part.prototype.setupGeometry = function (geometry, mesh, texture) {
        if (texture) {
            if (!MB.Library.geometries[texture]) {
                var file = this.loadTexture(PATH + 'data/parts/textures/' + texture + '.png');
                MB.Library.geometries[texture] = geometry;
                MB.Library.geometries[texture].materials[0].map = file;
                MB.Library.geometries[texture].materials[0].wireframe = (RENDER === 'WIREFRAME') ? true : false
            }
        } else {
            if (!MB.Library.geometries[mesh]) {
                MB.Library.geometries[mesh] = geometry
            }
        }
    };
    MB.Part.prototype.loadTexture = function (url, mapping, callback) {
        var image = new Image(),
            texture = new THREE.Texture(image, mapping);
        image.onload = function () {
            texture.needsUpdate = true;
            if (callback) callback(this)
        };
        image.crossOrigin = '';
        image.src = url;
        return texture
    };
    MB.Part.prototype.setupColour = function (colour) {
        if (!MB.Library.colours[colour]) {
            var materialColour = '0x' + COLOURS[colour].hex;
            var materialOpacity = COLOURS[colour].opacity;
            MB.Library.colours[colour] = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                ambient: new THREE.Color(materialColour),
                color: new THREE.Color(materialColour),
                opacity: materialOpacity,
                shininess: 100
            });
            MB.Library.colours[colour].wireframe = (RENDER === 'WIREFRAME') ? true : false;
            MB.Library.colours[colour].transparent = (COLOURS[colour].opacity < 1) ? true : false
        }
    };
    MB.Part.prototype.setColour = function (colour) {
        if (this.colour) {
            this.setupColour(colour);
            this.colour = colour;
            this.Object3D.material = MB.Library.colours[colour]
        }
    };

    MB.ObjectCount = 0;
    MB.Object3Ds = {};
    MB.Objects = {};
    MB.Library = {
        'colours': {},
        'geometries': {}
    };
```

The problem seems to be situated here:

```
if (texture) {
            if (!MB.Library.geometries[texture]) {
                var file = this.loadTexture(PATH + 'data/parts/textures/' + texture + '.png');
                MB.Library.geometries[texture] = geometry;
                MB.Library.geometries[texture].materials[0].map = file;
                MB.Library.geometries[texture].materials[0].wireframe = (RENDER === 'WIREFRAME') ? true : false
            }
```

and in the overall way I still handle textures.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

`Geometry` doesn't have a `materials` array anymore. The array has been moved to `MeshFaceMaterial`.

```
new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterials( materials ) );
```